# Error using metrics listed in Google's Metrics and dimensions

Tags: api, google-analytics, metrics, dimensions

I am using this code to query the api

```
    function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last 30 days.
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '30daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessionCount,ga:sessionDurationBucket,ga:users,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviews');
}
```

i get this error upon executing the code

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A114460017&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3AsessionCount%2Cga%3AsessionDurationBucket%2Cga%3Ausers%2Cga%3ApercentNewSessions%2Cga%3AbounceRate%2Cga%3Apageviews:
>   (400) Unknown metric(s): ga:sessionCount, ga:sessionDurationBucket

anyone ever experience? I do not understand why it does not recognize those metrics when it is listed

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_sessioncount

Answer (score 1):

If you look more closely into that documentation you will see that session count is not a metric, it's a dimension. The reason is that you want to be able to do breakdowns of metrics by session count (e.g. "show avg. duration of sessions for users with 3 sessions") and for that you need categorical data.

Even if you overlook the (not particularly distinctive) column heading in the table of contents (ga:sessionCount is in the "dimensions"-column) the fact that the datatype is a string would be a dead giveaway. Metrics are always numbers. Dimensions are always strings, even if they sometimes look like numbers.

Same goes for ga:sessionDurationBucket.

Look at this [example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) to see how dimensions are passed into the query via an array that holds optional parameters:

```
private function queryCoreReportingApi() {
  $optParams = array(
      'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
      'sort' => '-ga:sessions,ga:source',
      'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
      'max-results' => '25');

  return $service->data_ga->get(
      TABLE_ID,
      '2010-01-01',
      '2010-01-15',
      'ga:sessions',
      $optParams);
}
```

You'd need to construct a similar $optParams array:

```
$optParams = array(
          'dimensions' => 'ga:sessionCount,ga:sessionDurationBucket'
          ');
```

and pass it to your query:

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '30daysAgo',
       'today',
        $optParams,  
       'ga:users,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviews');
}
```

and remove the dimensions from the list of metrics.

Btw. Google has a [wonderful documentation page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en) on the difference between dimensions and metrics and how they are used in the reports.

Comment: When I print the results how will I do it? I currently am doing it like this             $rows = $results->getRows();
    $visits = $rows[0][0];
    $visitDuration = $rows[0][1];
    $avgVisitLength = $visits / $visitDuration;
    $uniqueVisitor = $rows[0][2];
    $percentNewSession = $rows[0][3];
    $bounceRate = $rows[0][4];
    $avgDuration = $rows[0][5];
    $pageView = $rows[0][6];
    $pagesPerVisit = $pageView / $visits;                                                           but now the data is all messed up, how will I call the results for the dimensions?

Comment: sorry i cant seem to figure out how to add a comment with code

Comment: Your rows will not start with the values for the dimensions, followed by the metrics for that dimension (so if you specify two dimensions in  your query users will not be at index  $rows[0][2] - that is the number of users that share the specific values for the selected dimensions).